# Expansion of function , defined on a open interval containing $0$ , in terms of $\sin$ function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

Let $I$ be an open interval in $\mathbb R$ containing $0$ and $f:I \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function , then is it true that $$\lim_{x \to  0}\dfrac {f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)\sin x - \dfrac{f''(0)\sin^2 x}2 }{x^2}=0 \space \space...(i)$$ ? I can prove the result if it is additionally given that $f''$ is continuous at $0$ , because then , for some $\theta \in (0,1) $ , we can write by Maclauraine's formula $\dfrac {f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)\sin x - \dfrac{f''(0)\sin^2 x}2 }{x^2}=\dfrac {(x-\sin x)f'(0) +\dfrac{f''(\theta x)}2x^2-\dfrac{f''(0)}2\sin^2x }{x^2}$ , now

by L'Hospital's rule  it can easily be checked that $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^2}=0$ and we also know that $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin^2x}{x^2}=1$ and if $f''$ is continuous at $0$ then we could write $\lim_{x\to 0}f''(\theta x)=f''(0)$ and we would be done but if it is not given that $f''(0)$ is continuous at $0$ then can we still infer about the limit $(i)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try L'Hospital's Rule $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x) - f(0) - f'(0)\sin x - \dfrac{f''(0)}{2}\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f'(x) - f'(0)\cos x - f''(0)\sin x\cos x}{2x}\text{ (by L'Hospital's Rule)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x} + f'(0)\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{x} - f''(0)\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \cos x\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(f''(0) + f'(0)\cdot 0 - f''(0)\cdot 1\cdot 1\right) = 0\end{aligned}$$ Note that we have not used continuity of $f''(x)$ just its existence at $x = 0$. Also we have used $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos^{2} x}{x(1 + \cos x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\sin x\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{1 + \cos x} = 0\cdot 1\cdot\frac{1}{2} = 0$$

Comment: Now wait $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f'(x)-f'(0)}x=lim_{x\to 0} f''(x) $ , given $\lim_{x \to 0} f''(x)$ exists ; and even if it exists , how do we know that $\lim_{x \to 0} f''(x)=f''(0)$ ?? aren't we using continuity of $f''$ then ...?

Comment: @SouvikDey: It seems you are a bit confused about definition of derivative. By definition $$f''(a) = \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f'(a + h) - f'(a)}{h}$$ and on putting $a = 0$ and replacing the variable $h$ by $x$ we get $$f''(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)\sin x-\frac{f''(0)\sin^2 x}2=\\
f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x-\frac{f''(0)x^2}2+f'(0)(x-\sin x)+\frac{f''(0)}2(x^2-\sin^2x)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\Bigl(f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x-\frac{f''(0)x^2}2\Bigr)=0,
$$

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}(f'(0)(x-\sin x))=0,
$$

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\Bigl(\frac{f''(0)}2(x^2-\sin^2x)\Bigr)=0.
$$

The first equality follows from the [Peano form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem).

Comment: how is $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\Bigl(f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x-\frac{f''(0)x^2}2\Bigr)=0$ ?

Comment: Because $f$ is $C^2$. Use the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $0$.

Comment: Are you sure Taylor expansion works ?? I have already tried it didn't work , see my work in the question

Comment: No, I am not sure. I was carried away by comparison with the fact that if $f'(0)$ exists then $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+o(x)$.

Comment: Well, now I am sure. It is the Peano form of the remainder .

Comment: Since the Peano form of the remainder is derivable by a repeated application of L'Hospital, I have given an answer using the L'Hospital directly.